# MongoDB multiple compound indexing will affect performance?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compound-index

Is creating multiple compound indexes for serving various types of queries is better?
   **or**
Is it better to
use a single compound index in a way that supports multiple queries(which is  hard to analysis and construct, since there are many number of queries).
My basic question is "**Does creating multiple compound indexes will slow down read/write operations?**"

Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any answer that fits all cases, but in general adding the right indexes will give you better performance. You will have less reads when accessing data. Calculating the index will cost you some performance, however if they are correct and used your db will perform better afterwards. Start with monitoring: [mongodb monitoring docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I know that indexing will cost some performance, but my question is creating multiple type of indexes will cost extra performance. For example: I have a two different indexes to server two different queries, my question is whether to combine the two indexes into single index is best or being two separate indexes is the best??

Comment: each index does have an added cost. but two -- one for each use case -- is preferred depending on measurements as suggested. versus messing up a data / object model.

Answer (score 0):

Indices will slow down writes but speed up reads. A high read to write ratio warrants one or more indices on commonly fetched fields (keys). For example our current system sees 25 writes to 20,000 reads (tps) so indices are beneficial to counter the wide margin. That being said, be mindful of retaining the mongo write lock as short as possible.

> MongoDB uses a readers-writer [1](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/) lock that allows concurrent reads
>   access to a database but gives exclusive access to a single write
>   operation. [mongodb docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/)